# How is the space complexity O(LogN) for rangeSumBST problem

Tags: trees, binary-trees, space-complexity, stacks

Recursive

```
class Solution {

    int ans;
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        ans = 0;
        dfs(root, L, R);
        return ans;
    }

    public void dfs(TreeNode node, int L, int R) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (L <= node.val && node.val <= R)
                ans += node.val;
            if (L < node.val)
                dfs(node.left, L, R);
            if (node.val < R)
                dfs(node.right, L, R);
        }
    }
}
```

Iterative

```
class Solution {
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        int ans = 0;
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack();
        stack.push(root);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode node = stack.pop();
            if (node != null) {
                if (L <= node.val && node.val <= R)
                    ans += node.val;
                if (L < node.val)
                    stack.push(node.left);
                if (node.val < R)
                    stack.push(node.right);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/solution/

Suppose `L` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `R` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, then wouldn't it traverse through all the nodes. Since we need to check the worst case, shouldn't it be O(N) instead of O(logN)

Answer (score 1):

The space complexity is the amount of space used, which is essentially the size of your call stack in your deepest line of recursion. The runtime is indeed $O(N)$ but the space complexity is $O(H)$ where H is the height of the tree.

Even following the link you provided, they state this:
[image]